# How to send stop not signed in users from navigating to particular pages in bottomNavBar

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a bottomNavbar with 4 pages, when the app first launches I want the home to be the first page users land on, but If they click on one of the other pages and are not signed in I want to redirect to the login Page. How do I first do a check to see if they are logged in or not and then redirect to the appropriate page.

my code:

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  //for the navigation
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  void _navigateBottomBar(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  final List<Widget> _pages = [
    const Home(),
    //The rest of these pages need to redirect to AuthGate and AuthGate needs an x button to navigate back
    const Book(), 
    const Appointments(), 
    ProfilePages()
  ];
  bool isAdmin = false;
  final dbhandler = DBHandler();

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    getUserType();
  }

  Future getUserType() async {
    // Get the currently logged-in user
    User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    String? userType = await dbhandler.getUserData(user!.uid);
    if (userType == 'admin') {
      setState(() => isAdmin = true);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => isAdmin
      ? const AdminPage()
      : Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,

          floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endFloat,
          //floating action button position to center
          body: _pages[_selectedIndex],
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
            selectedFontSize: 12, // Adjust the value as needed
            unselectedFontSize: 10, // Adjust the value as needed
            //fixedColor: Colors.blueAccent,
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
            currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
            onTap: _navigateBottomBar,
            type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
            items: const [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                label: 'Home',
                icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                label: 'Book',
                icon: Icon(Icons.app_registration),
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                label: 'Appointments',
                icon: Icon(Icons.assignment_outlined),
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                label: 'Settings',
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.settings,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [`FirebaseAuth`](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth) package to check if a user is logged in or not

Here’s a simple example of how you can do this :

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: NavigationPage(),
    );
  }
}

class NavigationPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NavigationPageState createState() => _NavigationPageState();
}

class _NavigationPageState extends State<NavigationPage> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  final List<Widget> _children = [
    HomePage(),
    MailPage(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _children[_currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: onTabTapped,
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.mail),
            label: 'Mail',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void onTabTapped(int index) async {
   final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
   
    if (user == null) {
      if (index != 0) {
        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => LoginPage(),
        ));
      }
    } else {
      if (index == 0) {
        setState(() {
          _currentIndex = 0;
        });
      } else if (index == 1) {
        setState(() {
          _currentIndex = 1;
        });
      }
    }
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Home Page'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Login Page'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MailPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Mail Page'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser` is used to get the current user. If the user is not logged in, this will return `null`